Android: insert one ArrayList into for() loop from multiple ArrayLists
I have a filter method in MainActivity for two ArrayLists, smallList and mainList.
How can I write for() loop code to select one of the lists based on the criteria shown, so that I don't have to use two for() loops?
private void filter(String searchText) {

    ArrayList<Card> searchList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Determine which RecyclerView list to use and then run a for() loop that     
    // searches the database for input search text.

    if (smallList != null && !smallList.isEmpty()) {
        for (Card cardItem : **smallList**) {
            if (cardItem.getInfo().contains(searchText)) {
                searchList.add(cardItem);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (Card cardItem : **mainList**) {
            if (cardItem.getInfo().contains(searchText)) {
                searchList.add(cardItem);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}


I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but anyway, here goes.
You simply first determine which List you want to search. Then you search only that List. Hence single for loop.
java.util.List<Card> list = smallList != null && !smallList.isEmpty() ? smallList : mainList;
for (Card cardItem : list) {
    if (cardItem.getInfo().contains(searchText)) {
        searchList.add(cardItem);
    }
}


Ok.  Can I easily add a few more lists easily with additional colons ":" after the "?"

@AJW I'm confused. In your question you specifically state that you have two lists and you want to choose one of them. Are you now saying that you have more than two lists?

Apologies for the confusion.  Yes, I may have more lists to add.

@AJW since the answers are based on your question which unambiguously says that there are exactly two lists, I suggest that you post a new question stating how many lists you have and what are the criteria for selecting one of those lists. As for this question, if it doesn't help you and you think it won't help others, then I suggest that you delete it. If you decide not to delete the question, then consider accepting one of the answers, or up-voting them (or both).

You could use Java Stream API to simplify the loops and ternary operator (or if-else, if you prefer that) to choose the list to use as a source.

To perform a computation, stream operations are composed into a stream pipeline. A stream pipeline consists of a source (which might be an array, a collection, a generator function, an I/O channel, etc), zero or more intermediate operations (which transform a stream into another stream, such as filter(Predicate)), and a terminal operation (which produces a result or side-effect, such as count() or forEach(Consumer)). Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed.

//choose source list and stream it
Stream<Card> stream = smallList != null && !smallList.isEmpty() 
        ? smallList.stream() 
        : mainList.stream();
List<Card> result = stream
        //filter matches
        .filter(card -> card.info().contains(searchText))
        //collect to a list
        .toList();


Chaosfire So am I understanding correctly that the results would be captured in a Stream and then put the results into a List with toList()?  And I could add a few more lists easily with additional colons ":" under the Stream and xList.stream()s?

@AJW The first question is answered in the docs I linked, I added citation. About the 2nd one, you could do that, but it seems it will become hard to read and support later. Better move the logic to pick a list into its own class.
